# How to test mysql queries using sqlalchemy and sqlite?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have the following code structure written in Python3.6, which I need to test using sqlite3 (because of standards defined in my project):

```
class BigSecretService:
    """ Class designed to make calculations based on data stored in MySQL. """
    def load_data(self):
        # load some data using sqlalchemy ORM

    def get_values_from_fields(self, fields):
        # here's getting values via sqlalchemy execute with raw query:
        self.sql_service.execute(SOME_QUERY)

    def process_data(self, data, values):
        # again execute some raw query
        # process data and put into result list
        return reuslt_list

    def make_calculations(self, params):
        data = self.load_data()
        values = self.get_values_from_fields(fields)
        result_vector = process_data(data, values)
```

SOME_QUERY is in separate module and it's format looks like this:

```
"SELECT SUM(some_field) FROM some_table WHERE col1 = :col1 AND col2 = :col2"
```

To cover make_calculations in my component test I designed awful patches:

```
class PatchedConnection:                                                                                                   
""" Class is used to transform queries to sqlite format before executing. """                                          
def __init__(self, connection, engine):                                                                                
    self.connection = connection                                                                                       
    self.engine = engine                                                                                               

def __call__(self):                                                                                                    
    conn = self.connection()                                                                                           
    conn.execute = self.patched_execute(conn.execute)                                                                  
    return conn                                                                                                        

def transform_date(self, date):                                                                                        
    try:                                                                                                               
        # quick check just for testing                                                                                 
        if '+00:00' in date:                                                                                           
            date = date.replace('T', ' ').replace('+00:00', '.000000')                                                 
    finally:                                                                                                           
        return date                                                                                                    

def patched_execute(self, f_execute):                                                                                  
    def prepare_args_for_sqlite(query, *args):                                                                         
        # check if query is in sqlite format                                                                           
        if args:                                                                                                       
            if '?' in str(query):                                                                                      
                args = list(map(self.transform_date, list(args[0].values())))                                          
                return self.engine.execute(str(query), args)                                                           
            return f_execute(query, args[0])                                                                           
        else:                                                                                                          
            return f_execute(query)                                                                                    
    return prepare_args_for_sqlite
```

Then in test it looks like this:

```
   QUERY_TEMPLATE_SQLITE = 'SELECT SUM(some_field) FROM some_table WHERE col1 = ? AND col2 = ?'
   with mock.patch('path_to_my_service.SOME_QUERY', QUERY_TEMPLATE_SQLITE):           
      self.sql_service.get_connection = PatchedConnection(self.sql_service.get_connection, self.engine)               
      response = self.client.simulate_post("/v1/secret_service/make_calculations",                      
                                           headers=self.auth_header,                                          
                                           body=json.dumps(payload))                                          

      self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)    
      # then check response.text
```

It works so far, but I believe there must be much better solution. Moreover, in patched_execute args from dict are being converted to list, and who knows if order of dict values will be the same all the time.
So, my question is how to perform such testing in a correct way with given tools?

Comment: If your program is written to use MySQL, it should be tested with MySQL, not a completely different database engine.

Comment: It's not an integration test, just component, and that's how it is established in my project before me )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to intercept and manipulate the SQL being sent to the database then using core events https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/events.html would be the most straightforward way of doing this. The `before_cursor_execute` event would suit your purposes as outlined in the following example from the SQLAlchemy documentation.

```
@event.listens_for(engine, "before_cursor_execute", retval=True)
def before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, parameters, context, executemany):
    # do something with statement, parameters
    return statement, parameters
```

From the example you have given however, I'm not sure that this is necessary. The MySQL query you have listed is also a valid SQLite query and needs no manipulation. Also if you pass your parameters as python objects, rather than as strings, then again no manipulation should be needed as SQLAlchemy will map these correctly to the backend.

Comment: Thank for that hook. And about manipulations - it's really needed because of real internal structure of my project.